# Updating Next_ID column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
VehicleID Reg_ID Next_RegID EntryDate
330034    9111   NULL        2010-12-06 00:00:00
330034    9113   NULL        2010-12-09 00:00:00
```

On the first row I need to update the Next_RegId column with the Reg_ID of the second row where VehicleId or (VIN/ChassisNumber) is the same. The Next_RegID column on the last entry should remain Null.

I've created a while loop procedure which works perfectly, but with millions of records in the table it takes ages to complete. Therefore, I was wondering if any of you dealt with this kind of a problem and have a solution for it.

Here's the procedure I wrote, and thanks in advance for all your help:

```
Declare @i as integer;
Declare @x as integer;
Declare @y as integer

Set @i= (Select Max(RID) from TempRegistration)
Set @x= 0
Set @y= 1
Declare @curChassis as nvarchar(100)
Declare @nextChassis as nvarchar(100)

  While (@x <= @i)
  Begin
set @curChassis = (Select ChassisNumber from TempRegistration where RID = @x)
set @nextChassis = (Select ChassisNumber from TempRegistration where RID = @y)

If (@curChassis = @nextChassis)
Begin
    Update Registration set NextRegistrationId = (Select RegistrationId from      TempRegistration where RID = @y)
    Where RegistrationId = (Select RegistrationId from TempRegistration where RID = @x)
End

Set @x = @x + 1
Set @y = @y + 1

Print(@x)
    End
```

TempRegistration is a temporary table I've created to assign a row_id which guides the while loop to assign the Reg_ID to the Next_RegId on the previous row.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with one UPDATE query. You haven't mentioned your RDBMS so...

For MSSQL:

```
Update Registration as t1
set NextRegistrationId = (Select TOP 1 RegistrationId 
                                       from Registration
                                       where RID = t1.RID 
                                         and EntryDate>t1.EntryDate
                                       order by EntryDate DESC)
```

For MySQL

```
Update Registration as t1
set NextRegistrationId = (Select RegistrationId 
                                       from Registration 
                                       where RID = t1.RID 
                                          and EntryDate>t1.EntryDate
                                       order by EntryDate DESC 
                                       LIMIT 1)
```

If RID's are increasing with EntryDate then

```
Update Registration as t1
set NextRegistrationId = (Select MIN(RegistrationId) 
                                       from Registration 
                                       where RID = t1.RID
                                       and EntryDate>t1.EntryDate
                          )
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. The only thing I had to change is 'Where VehicleID = t1.VehicleId and RID < t1.RID' as VehicleID is the constant and RID is never equal to t1.RID if EntryDate > t2.EntryDate. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested and it seems to be working but this version uses a `CTE` (SQL Server)

```
with RegDetails as
(
select VehicleID, Reg_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY EntryDate) AS ROWNUMBER
FROM dbo.Vehicle)
UPDATE a SET a.Next_RegID = b.Reg_ID
FROM RegDetails b
INNER JOIN dbo.Vehicle a ON (a.VehicleID = b.VehicleID)
WHERE b.ROWNUMBER = 2 and a.Next_RegID IS NULL and a.Reg_ID != b.Reg_ID
```